# What was the anticipated use of the reserved parameter on CoInitialize

Tags: windows, com, history

Its been about 16 years now since it was created and I still don't know why there was a reserved parameter in the [CoInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678543.aspx) method. Does anyone know (or is able to make an intelligent guess about) why this parameter was added and what the anticipated use was?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually not for future use, but for backward compatibility. Read: [Why was the ability to specify an allocator during CoInitialize removed from the system?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2007/02/08/why-was-the-ability-to-specify-an-allocator-during-coinitialize-removed-from-the-system.aspx) by @Larry Osterman, who actually hangs around here occasionally...

In short: that argument used to allow you to specify a custom allocator. But since that feature has been misused, it was deprecated.